# Colorbox not working as expected with ajax form

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I'm not so good in coding. I try to use Colorbox to show one of my page in. This page has a contact form. Unfortunately if I open this page in Colorbox and click the submit button, unfortunately Colorbox closing. (I don't really understand but maybe Colorbox make a simple http request not an ajax request?)

In summary, I want to use colorbox to show my contact form and am having trouble getting it to work.

My contact form php:

```
   <div class="text">
                                                    <div class="contacter_head" style="border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc; color:#124C7A">Contact form!</div>
                                                <form id="contactform" name="contactform" method="post" action="submit_contact.php">
    
    <div class="my_left_box">
                                                <p>name *   </p>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['name']?>" id="name" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" />
                                                <p>Email* </p>
                                                <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['email']?>" id="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" />
                                                <p>subject </p>
                                                <input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo $_GET['sbject'];?>" />
                                                <p>Phone</p>
                                                <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post']['phone']; unset($_SESSION['post']['phone']);?>" id="phone" class="validate[onlyNumber]" />
                                                <p>Captcha</p>
                                                    <label for="captcha_contact"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]] captcha_aj" name="captcha" id="captcha" />
                                                
                                                    </div>                                          
                                                <div class="my_right_box">
                                                <p>Message</p>
                                                <textarea name="message" id="message_aj" rows="6" cols="5" class="validate[required]"><?=$_SESSION['post']['message']?></textarea>
                                                
                                                <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" id="button" class="button medium"/>
                                                     <?=$str?>          <img id="loading" src="images/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" />
                                                        </form>
                                            <?=$success?>               
        
                                            <div id="errOffset">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
        
    
                                            
                                            
                                                
                            
                                            </div>
```

That's my ajax snippet which is works well if I open contact form php directly:

```
var use_ajax=true;
$.validationEngine.settings={};


 $("#contactform").validationEngine({
    inlineValidation: false,
    promptPosition: "centerRight",
    success :  function(){use_ajax=true},
    failure : function(){use_ajax=false;}
 })

 $("#contactform").submit(function(e){
     alert("itt");
        if(use_ajax)
        {
            $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
            $.post('submit_contact.php',$(this).serialize()+'&ajax=1',
            
                function(data){
                    if(parseInt(data)==-1)
                        $.validationEngine.buildPrompt("#captcha","* Captcha error","error");
                        
                    else
                    {
                        $("#ajanlat-form").hide('slow').after('<h1>Thank you,.</h1>');
                    }
                    
                    $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                }
            
            );
        }
        e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you opening the popup via ColorBox?  I would suggest considering using ColorBox's **iFrame** option as that will open the popup in its own "html sandbox".  Additionally, if the native Submit event still causes you problems, consider trapping it with Jquery, preventing default behavior, and initiating the form action on your own.

PS. A link to your project would help the community help you.